# couldn't get TURN REST API to work properly

Tags: node.js, webrtc, rfc5766turnserver

I am trying to generate the username and password in node.js. It seems my password doesnot match with the one generated by TURN server.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
var turn_user='arafat';
 var timestamp= Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) ;
 var turn_username=turn_user+':'+timestamp; 
 var turn_password=crypto.createHmac('sha1','abc').update(turn_username).digest('base64');
 var turnCredentials={};
 turnCredentials.username=turn_username;
 turnCredentials.password=turn_password;
```

and my server url is:

```
var server = { iceServers: [ {url: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}, //google's stun server 
{url: "stun:23.21.150.121"}, //mozilla's stun server
 {url: "turn:"+url, credential: turnCredentials.password, username: turnCredentials.username} // our working turn server 
] }
```

Here is the message I am getting from turn server:

ERROR: check_stun_auth: Cannot find credentials of user

Answer (score 0):

Note that the TURN REST API documentation says the timestamp is an indication of when the credentials expire.

```
var timestamp= Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) ;
var turn_username=turn_user+':'+timestamp;
```

Here, you use the current time as the expiration. I'd recommend adding a few minutes to give the peers some time to create the TURN allocation:

```
var timestamp= Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 300;
```